# SQL Sum function of a decimal column returns int instead of decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of decimal type and i need to use the sum function on it like this:

```
   declare @credit decimal = (select
                               (    select ISNULL(SUM(Convert(DECIMAL(13,2), Amount)),0)
                                    from TransactionDetail as t1
                                    where t1.AccountFrom = @fromAccount and t1.AccountTo = @toAccount
                               ) -     
                               (    select ISNULL(SUM(Convert(DECIMAL(13,2),Amount)),0)
                                    from TransactionDetail as t1
                                    where t1.AccountFrom = @toAccount  and t1.AccountTo = @fromAccount
                               ) 
                           )
select @credit
```

The output should be a decimal number like :
13.56

However, the result is always int, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `scale` is 0.  If you want the result as a particular format, try explicitly adding precision and scale to the variable:

```
declare @credit decimal(13, 2) = (select . . .
```

This behavior is well [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the
>   decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the
>   maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. The maximum
>   number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the
>   decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p.  cSale can be
>   specified only if precision is specified. **The default scale is 0;**

Comment: I missed that, Thank you very much